# Multiple table data selection with same structure in Codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, union

How to select data from multiple tables all with same structure but different data in mysql from CodeIgniter?

I have multiple inner join table along with two tables of similar structure. Can we include two tables in select statement in CodeIgniter ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use join. You can simply do it by [`Union`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html).

```
$condition_array = 'emep1.is_deleted ="0")';
$this->db->select("emep1.emp_id, emep1.emp_name, emep1.salary");
$this->db->from('tbl_emp as emp1');
$this->db->where($condition_array);
$query1 = $this->db->get_compiled_select();

$condition_array = 'emep2.is_deleted ="0")';
$this->db->select("emep2.emp_id, emep2.emp_name, emep2.salary");
$this->db->from('tbl_emp2 as emp2');
$this->db->where($condition_array);

//Group by if you needed
$this->db->group_by('emp1.emp_id');
$query2 = $this->db->get_compiled_select();

$query = $this->db->query("select * from (" . $query1 . " UNION " . $query2 . ") as combine_table_data ORDER BY emp_id desc");
return $query->result_array();
```

Note: In select statement You should have same field.

Comment: Thank you. But As I have to use alias name for table I used view to join two tables and retrieved the result in desired format